# How do I write this short hand in Java?

Tags: java, conditional-operator, shorthand

```js
str = str.replace(fraction, replacement[1] || replacement[0]);
```

I want to replace with [1] if [1] is not "" or undefined or null, or else replace with [0] if [1] is "" or undefined or null. I know I can do this with a 3-5 lines of if else, but can I do it in one like very short like I wrote above in Java?

Comment: Your meaning isn't clear, it would help if those variables were defined in the code and we had some additional code for context.  But probably something like `(replacement[1] != null && !replacement[1].isBlank()) ? replacement[1] : replacement[0]`

Comment: @markspace Oh thank you! That's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is not a very concise language by nature. The most concise way to do what you're asking is probably something like markspace's comment:

```java
str = str.replace(fraction, (replacement[1] != null && !replacement[1].isBlank()) ? replacement[1] : replacement[0]);
```

This uses a [ternary operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator) to select between `replacement[1]` and `replacement[0]`.

For a middle ground, you could also separate this ternary operation onto a separate line:

```java
char replacementChar = (replacement[1] != null && !replacement[1].isBlank()) ? replacement[1] : replacement[0];
str = str.replace(fraction, replacementChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @markspace for your answer!

I solved it with

```java
str = str.replaceAll(fraction, replacement[1] != null && !replacement[1].isEmpty() ? replacement[1] : replacement[0])
```